# Set the colour of the dropdown button while hovering its listed items

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have made the following dropdown button ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tevulezupe/edit?html,output)). Currently, when the dropdown list is open, and when I hover over the listed items, the button itself changes its colour to dark blue. I don't want this to happen; I want it to change its color to `#1abc9c`. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    
    .rb .btn.btn-primary {
        background-color: #1abc9c;
        border-color: white
    }

    .rb .btn.btn-primary:hover {
        background-color: #2fe2bf;
    }

    .rb .btn.btn-primary:focus {
        outline: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .rb .btn.btn-primary:active {
        border-color: white;
        background-color: #1abc9c;
    }

    .rb .dropdown-toggle  {
        border-color: white !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="rb">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
      </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:** I have a better version [here](https://jsbin.com/nopebojivo/1/edit?html,output). Now, while pressing the `normal` button above, we see the colour changes to a slightly darker blue, and when we release the pressing, the colour changes back to a brighter blue. I want to have the same effect on the dropdown button: ie, press the button ==> a slightly darker blue ==> release the button ==> a brighter blue and the dropdown list is shown ==> press the button ==> a slightly darker blue ==> release the button ==> a brighter blue and the dropdown list is hidden.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: you want it to stay the same color until the user clicks it again?

Comment: please see my last edit in the end of the OP...

Comment: yes its possible. Just like the first answer I gave, you need to inspect the state of the button using dev tools, and edit it at each state you want to change the color - if you want someone to do it for you, offer to pay them.

Comment: It is hard to inspect the state of the button that is **being** pressed...

Comment: there is only 4 potential states - active, focus, hover, and visited. You can rule out hover since hover would not include the button being pressed, you can also rule out visited since the button is not a visited link. So you've got two potential states. Force the state of the button on each one and modify css styles until you get the one you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this i hope it will helpful to you.

```
.rb .dropdown:active .btn-primary:active {
    background-color: #1abc9c !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works... [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/rohocimoqa/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome developer tools you can isolate the state of the DOM element you want to change, in this case it is

```
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus {
      background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

Try it out in your css and you can see it work

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because you are using Bootstrap. When a button is focused, Bootstrap adds this rule : `background-color: #204d74;`

So you need to add a `background-color:#1abc9c` on your `.btn-primary` when it's `:focus` like this :

```
.rb .btn.btn-primary:focus {
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color:#1abc9c;
}
```